# How to change Kerbal contracts settings during play or in save?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

I made mistake. I hate part testing contracts but I enabled them when I was starting new game. Is there a way to change it now, without restarting my career? I find the initial stages pretty boring and do not want to go thorough them gain.

Just ignoring these contracts is not good enough, because amount of contracts I see is limited and these prevent other ones from appearing.

Just lowering a chance for part testing contracts would be a good enough solution. I don't mind if one in ten is of this kind. I do mind if nine in ten is.

Comment: Why don't you decline those contracts?

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer I do, but what I get in their place are similar contacts.

Comment: How did you enable them when you started a new game? Previous versions didn't let you choose contract types to enable/disable, and I wasn't familiar with the latest update so I started it up to see, but I cannot find any options to selectively enable/disable contract types. I know there are mods that *do* provide that ability though — are you using one? (Or am I just missing something obvious in the new version?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not aware how you would disable a type of contract when starting the game in unmodded KSP, however the default contract system is dynamic, and adjusts based on what contracts you accept and ignore.

Each contract type (and each celestial body) has a weight, and that weight determines the chance of it appearing. Accepting contracts increases the weight of that type of contracts, ignoring or declining contracts reduces their weight.

So **if you keep ignoring or declining the part contracts, you'll start seeing less of them**. Declining gets rid of them faster than ignoring, but costs a bit of reputation.

The specific weight constants are located in the Contracts.cfg file, as of KSP 1.2.1 they are:

- WeightDefault = 30 // The default weight new contract types start with
- WeightMinimum = 10 // The minimum weight that contracts can have from declining them
- WeightMaximum = 90 // The maximum weight that contracts can have from accepting them
- WeightAcceptDelta = 12 // How much accepting contracts affects their weight
- WeightDeclineDelta = -8 // How much declining contracts affects their weight
- WeightWithdrawReadDelta = -2 // How much an expired contract that was read affects their weight
- WeightWithdrawSeenDelta = -1 // How much an expired contract that was seen (showed up in mission control) affects their weight

Now, if you really want to get rid of all the part contracts right away, you can go into your *Kerbal Space Program/saves/<savegame_name>* folder, open up the *persistent.sfs* file with your favorite text editor, find the part which says *WEIGHTS*, and edit those weights to whatever suits your fancy. In your case, you would want the *PartTest* variable in the *WEIGHTS* section.

From my brief testing, setting the weight to zero seems to disable the generation of that type of contracts completely.

Comment: And always make a backup of your `persistent.sfs` first, of course!